# Formula Error: Formula Error: Illegal character '~'

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv

Hello I am using version 2.1 of Larvel Excel with Laravel version 5.2 and running into an illegal character error.

https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/getting-started/

I am trying to export an entire table to an .xlsx file and I am running into an illegal character. I have done a ton of searching online and cant seem to find any reason why this character would be illegal in a spreadsheet. I have tried doing a CSV as well and that doesn't seem to work. Here is the error.

```
PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception in Cell.php line 293: FTP Accounts!F14 -> Formula Error: Illegal character '~'
```

If I go to the column content that is causing the error and get rid of the ~ it works. Is there anyway to get around this without changing the content of the cells with ~ to without one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: its not illegal in the spreadsheet, its illegal in the formula.

Comment: Possibly you have a value in your table that looks like a formula i.e. starts with '='?

Comment: If you know there aren't any formulas in the spread sheet you can just prepend a `'` to the beginning of your strings.

Comment: Like the backslash, the tilde (e.g. `~`) character is used by some programming/scripting environments as an **escape character**. Typically, to escape an escape character, you would double it up; e.g. `~~`. For example, to Find an asterisk (e.g. `*`) which is reserved for use as a wildcard you would actually Find `~*`.